# Makefile for kernel kecho command issue

Tags: linux, makefile, kernel

This a makefile for compiling the kernel module.

```
# Makefile – makefile of our first driver
#  
# if KERNELRELEASE is defined, we've been invoked from the
# kernel build system and can use its language.
ifneq (${KERNELRELEASE},)

 obj-m = first-driver.o

# Otherwise we were called directly from the command line.
# Invoke the kernel build system.
else
KERNEL_SOURCE := /lib/modules/2.6.32-504.8.1.el6.x86_64/build
PWD := $(shell pwd)
default: 
        ${MAKE} -C ${KERNEL_SOURCE} SUBDIRS=${PWD} modules
        @echo kernel first-driver is ready
        @$(kecho) 'Kernel: $@ is ready' 

clean:
        ${MAKE} -C ${KERNEL_SOURCE} SUBDIRS=${PWD} clean
endif

.PHONY : install remove

install :
        sudo insmod first-driver.ko

remove :
        sudo rmmod first-driver
```

Here I have used echo and kecho as per kernel makefile documantation but it giving the following error:

```
make -C /lib/modules/2.6.32-504.8.1.el6.x86_64/build SUBDIRS=/home/betatest/Device-Driver-Test modules
make[1]: Entering directory '/usr/src/kernels/2.6.32-504.8.1.el6.x86_64'
  Building modules, stage 2.
  MODPOST 1 modules
make[1]: Leaving directory '/usr/src/kernels/2.6.32-504.8.1.el6.x86_64'
kernel first-driver is ready
make: Kernel: default is ready: Command not found
Makefile:16: recipe for target 'default' failed
make: *** [default] Error 127
```

I am using GNU make version 4.1 and gcc version 4.4.7 where am I going wrong. Thanks.....

Comment: Can you do `echo $(kecho)` after the line `@echo kernel first-driver is ready` and post the output?

Comment: kecho is defined in makefile.include file as kecho = echo

Comment: Did my solution solved your problem or you included the makefile.include file in the above makefile?

Comment: makefile.include is in kernel headers that is by default included when compiling a kernel module.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What is `kecho` variable's is assigned to? in the line `@$(kecho) 'Kernel: $@ is ready'` `kecho`'s value is null so the make considers only `@$(kecho) 'Kernel: $@ is ready'` as a rule.

Did you forget to assign kecho to something at the beginning of the file? Like

`kecho='echo'`